# Webpack + TS: Can't make Node.js happy with 'module' or 'commonjs' type

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

This is my first time setting up Webpack manually, and Typescript is in the mix.

The project builds successfully, but when running the build with `yarn start` there's the following error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\karlo\Projects\reports_server\node_modules\openai\dist\index.js from C:\Users\karlo\Projects\reports_server\dist\server.js not supported.
```

The error is thrown by this line `module.exports = require("openai");` in the output server file. The original .ts files use ES6 imports, but it seems TS or Webpack automatically convert these to CommonJS. Pressing on, let's follow the advice seen online for this error:

*Modify package.json to include `"type": "module"`*

Oh boy. Now the following error pops up:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

That's being thrown by this line: `module.exports = require("apollo-server");`

The same syntax as the line causing the previous error, and actually just above it in the code.

I'm feeling quite stuck in the middle and kicking myself for not using boilerplate... but at the same time really want to understand where things have gone wrong. If you feel you might know and need more info, please say so.

**UPDATE**
If anyone has an issue with the `openai` module in the future, switching to `openai-api` immediately fixed things. Why exactly `openai` breaks so spectacularly is still unknown, so this question remains open.

Comment: Writing this has brought up a possibility. Perhaps the original fault lies with the openai module I'm attempting to import. Are all ES modules unable to be included with require()? If so, isn't it strange Webpack or TS would default to outputting CommonJS? I've played with changing Webpack's target from 'node' to 'es5' or something like it, but this creates a litany of new, even more terrifying errors. Send help.

Comment: This is somehow related to the `openai` module. I switched to an alternative package and the error went away. Perhaps it's the way they packaged the module?